SSRS Report Builder - Keep Everthing in One Page but in multiple sheets in excel
I don't believe there is a solution to this problem but here it comes!
I have a report with multiple tables and tablixes with different number of columns as well as column widths. In the process of making the export to excel as friendly as possible, I had to break it into multiple excel sheets, in order to avoid double columns and/or added blank columns.
Is there a way to keep everything together in one page on the report preview and the splitting to occur only when exporting to excel?
Not sure what to try, assigning different page names to tablixes but without the page breaks keeps everything in one page both on preview and on export.

I've not tried this so it's a guess but try adding thin rectangles where you want the page breaks to be, set the page names on those rectangles and set the page break properties to 'before' (probably). Now set the 'hidden' property of these rectangles to =Globals!Renderformat.Isinteractive, so if it is interactive (on screen) then hidden will be true so the page breaks should not render.

No problem, I'll add this as an answer so you can accept it, this will help others looking for answers to similar questions. It will also give you reputation which allows you to do more on SO eventually (I get some too but I have enough ! :) )

More than happy to accept it! Cheers and thanks again for the help!

You can do this by adding rectangles at the points where you want the page breaks. These can be as small as you like as they only serve to give a page break.
Set the page break properties on the rectangles to 'after'. Set the page name on the rectangles as you need.
Finally, set the Hidden property of the rectangles to =Globals!Renderformat.Isinteractive. This means that when the report is being viewed as default Isinteracive will be true and the rectangles will be hidden and the page breaks ignored.
When rendered in any other format (e.g. Excel) the opposite will be true and the rectangles will be rendered along with their associated page breaks.
